# AutoRotation and supporting Landscape and Portrait

Tags: objective-c, xcode, rotation

Hi I am trying to make my Iphone application allow all orientations and currently I am using a TableViewController, I edited the code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
//(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

My app does not change at all when I rotate it merely displays a table sideways? How do I get it to rotate with the device? Thanks

Also, I am using a navigation controller at the beginning and have multiple segues which go to other views

Comment: If you are using navigation controller make sure that the rootviewcontroller and following pushed view controllers also supports all orientations.

Comment: How do I check the if the navigation controller supports rotation? I only know how to check in the summary section of the project under target.

Comment: YOu should have set a rootviewcontorller when you initialized your navigation controller.At first make sure it supports it and then follow all view controller which could be pushed on to that one.make sure you have implemented shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in those viewcontrooolers

Comment: I have a tab bar controller with two tabs which then go to navigation controllers and then the view controllers. I know how to check the view controllers but how do I check the tab controller and the navigation controller?

Comment: I got it, not all the views supported the rotation so I had to change them all to yes even the second tab ones, thanks you helped a lot

Comment: you are welcome you can just up vote as thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Check ur projects .plist file and make sure are there 4 elements for key "Supported interface orientations

as below:
   Supported interface orientations:

```
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

if not all these please add them either from .plist file or from xcode editor by selecting the device icons

Comment: how do u check a plist? I went to the project and clicked on target and under the supported device orientation in summary it supports all but upside down which I'm not concerned about

Comment: Upside down means "Home" button will be on up side.. means ur device will be rotate 180 degree..Although You can check .plist by going in ur project folders "supporting Files" under this folder u will see a project named.plist file.

Comment: are u running app on iPhone or iPad if iPad then it may be in rotation lock in settings.

Comment: My Plist has the required strings and the application is universal atm